# React-Redux How to call new dispatch based on a success condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have banged around in this for a while now. Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392964/react-redux-dispatch-action-after-another-action) question but its not quite what I want.

In a nutshell... I have const expression = to a function that is chained to another function that makes an API call in a separate file to LoginContainer but in the same folder -(its called reducer.js but has the actions as well at this stage). If successful it receives a token which it saves in local storage. this works fine.

Here it is.

```
import { fetch, addTask } from 'domain-task'
import { saveJwt, clearJwt } from '../auth/jwt'
import { handleErrors } from '../utils/http'

const REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN'
const RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN'
const ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN'
const REQUEST_USER = 'REQUEST_USER'
const RECEIVE_USER = 'RECEIVE_USER'
const ERROR_USER = 'ERROR_USER'

// ******************* action
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }



import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Login from './Login'
import { requestLoginToken } from './reducer'

class LoginContainer extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isAuthorised) {
      this.context.router.push('/')
    }
  }

  submit = (values) => {
    console.log('got values!', values)
    this.props.requestLoginToken(values.username, values.password)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Login onSubmit={this.submit} />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthorised: state.login.isAuthorised,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  requestLoginToken: (username, password) => dispatch(requestLoginToken(username, password)),
  //requestSelectData: (values = {}) => dispatch(requestSelectData(values = {})),
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

In the loginContainer (above), Once the "userName" and "password" have been entered and  the submit button clicked, the expression "requestLoginToken" is called.

**My Problem**

I want to fetch a significant amount of data based on the above expression "requestLoginToken" successfully saving a JWT token into local storage. It does this successfully now with the right username and password.

I know I can't make another call from within the expression "requestLoginToken" using a ".then" as it specifically needs to retrieve and then save a token first - I have to wait till it finishes to know if I have a token.  I need to run a second expression that only gets run if this promise is successful ie via a conditional statement. "If (JWT) etc"

1) Could someone tell me where and how I add this conditional statement. Im thinking its in the Logincontainer in the submit? ..how do would I structure the condition?

2) Where and how do I add the const = function for the retrieval of the data eg if I place it in another separate file do I still or even need to register it in mapDispatchToProps in the loginContainer etc

**EDIT**

Taking Nate Kimball's answer and running with it. Decided to split it out into its own "const" called "selectData" which I plan to call right underneath the line "saveJwt(data)".

However I find I am now getting an error:

> Unexpected Token , expected

Its on the very last line of the following code block below.. (right curly bracket has red under it) checked it for sytax but cant workout why.

I think the approach is correct though.

```
const selectData = () => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

  const token = jwt.access_token
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
  const selectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
        .catch(error => {
          clearJwt()
          dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't nest a second fetch from within your action after a successful call:

```js
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)
        // Since this is where you receive your login token,
        // You can dispatch an action to acknowledge you're fetching:
        dispatch({ type: SECOND_DATA_FETCHING })
        // This is also where you would make your next call:
        fetch('/api/etc', { ...config })
        .then(response => {
            // You can use your reducer to both inform a successful call &
            // store the received data
            dispatch({ type: SECOND_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Let your app know the call was unsuccessful:
            dispatch({ type: SECOND_DATA_FAILED, payload: error.message })
        })

        // Note: if you don't like the nested ugliness, you could optionally
        // put this entire nested fetch chain into a separate action and just 
        // dispatch that when you get your token.
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

At that point, all you need to do is update your mapStateToProps function in your component to receive the data and/or the status of that second layer of fetched data:

```js
// Make sure you have a default status for that second data
// just in case your token call fails. 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthorised: state.login.isAuthorised,
  secondData: state.login.secondData,
  secondDataStatus: state.login.secondDataStatus
})
```

Comment: I believe this is the best way to go - I did put something together and as suggested split it off into its own expression.. However I am getting a sytax error indicating i need to have a comma " , " on the very last curly bracket. Could someone have quick look and see if there is an obvious error etc I voted this up by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requestLoginToken` in another action creator:

```
function loginAndFetch() {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch(requestLoginToken()).then(token => {
          return fetch(...)  // use token here
      })
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could save the token you got to the store, then have another component listen to changes to the token and dispatch another action when the token changes.

```
class Container extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.token != prevProps.token) {
            dispatch(fetchSignificantAmountOfData())
        }
    } 
}
```

*Container is connected and maps the stored token into `props.token`*

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom middleware to solve this problem like this:

https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/redux/middleware/clientMiddleware.js

And then, you can use the action like this:

```
export function myAction() {
  return {
    types: [LOAD, SUCESS, FAIL],
    promise: (client) => client.get('/some_api')
  };
}
```

The middleware will dispatch the LOAD reducer first, then if promise is resolve, it call SUCESS; Otherwise, FAIL is called.